# Declare and fill time.struct_time type variable

Tags: python-3.x

! Hi, folks!
I'm trying to convert bcd coded date-time data I get from I2C connected RTC to `time.struct_time` so I can use it later as a native type. The RTC returns an array, that should be decoded before it can be used. The source code is something like this:

```
import time
...
def bcd2dec(bcd):
  return(10 * (bcd >> 4) + (bcd & 0x0F))
...
rtcdata = [36, 54, 35, 48, 35, 36, 32] # BCD coded datetime from RTC
rtc_time = time.struct_time(
  tm_year   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[6]),
  tm_mon    = bcd2dec(rtcdata[5] & 0x1F), # last 5 bits
  tm_mday   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[3] & 0x3F), # last 6 bits
  tm_hour   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[2] & 0x3F), # last 6 bits
  tm_min    = bcd2dec(rtcdata[1] & 0x7F), # last 7 bits
  tm_sec    = bcd2dec(rtcdata[0] & 0x7F), # last 7 bits
  tm_wday   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[4] & 0x07) # last 3 bits
)
```

But this doesn't work. I spent several hours on trying to figure out how to fill this 'named tuple' with no luck. Can somebody suggest hot to declare such variable and fill all the corresponding properties by theirs names?

Answer (score 0):

After several more painful hours of struggling and searching through the Internet I was able to compose a solution. But actually I found it is more readable to go away with just `rtc_time = time.struct_time(())` solution. May be this will help someone.

```
import time
from collections import namedtuple
...
def bcd2dec(bcd):
  return(10 * (bcd >> 4) + (bcd & 0x0F))
...

struct_time_ = namedtuple('struct_time', ['tm_year', 'tm_mon', 'tm_mday', 'tm_hour', 'tm_min', 'tm_sec', 'tm_wday', 'tm_yday', 'tm_isdst'])

rtcdata = [36, 54, 35, 48, 35, 36, 32] # BCD coded datetime from RTC

rtc_time = struct_time_(
  tm_sec    = bcd2dec(rtcdata[0] & 0x7F), # last 7 bits
  tm_min    = bcd2dec(rtcdata[1] & 0x7F), # last 7 bits
  tm_hour   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[2] & 0x3F), # last 6 bits
  tm_mday   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[3] & 0x3F), # last 6 bits
  tm_wday   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[4] & 0x07), # last 3 bits
  tm_mon    = bcd2dec(rtcdata[5] & 0x1F), # last 5 bits
  tm_year   = bcd2dec(rtcdata[6]),
  tm_yday   = 0,
  tm_isdst  = -1
)
```